Byte Buffer Ring Buffer type in ESP32
This is my first attempt to use a ring buffer. In my project, I receive data through a loRa module (the Reyax RYLR998 specifically) and push every message I receive to the ring buffer.
I defined a struct for the data I receive from the LoRa module:
typedef struct LoraData {
  char *Address;
  char *DataLength;
  char *Data;
  char *SignalStrength;
  char *SignalNoise;
} Lora_Data_t;

My definition for the ring buffer:
#define RINGBUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define RINGBUFFER_TYPE RINGBUF_TYPE_BYTEBUF
...
...
...
void app_main(void) {
// ring buffer init
  data_in_rbuf_handle = xRingbufferCreate(RINGBUFFER_SIZE, RINGBUFFER_TYPE);
  if (data_in_rbuf_handle == NULL) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to create ring buffer\n");
  } else {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ring Buffer 'data_in_rbuf_handle' !!!CREATED!!!");
  }
  ...
  ...
}

When I receive the data, I push it to the buffer:
// send the received block to ring buffer
   UBaseType_t res_send_rbuf =
       xRingbufferSend(data_in_rbuf_handle, Lora_data.Data,
                       strlen(Lora_data.Data), pdMS_TO_TICKS(DELAY / 10));
   if (res_send_rbuf != pdTRUE) {
     ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to send item");
   } else {
     ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Item sent to ring buffer");
     ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ring Buffer free space: <%zu>",
              xRingbufferGetCurFreeSize(data_in_rbuf_handle));
   }

I may not be using the ring buffer feature in an efficient way, because I'm not running two tasks at the same time, the tasl receiving the data pushes it to the buffer, and when all data is received, I notify another taslk to start processing that data.
So in the processing task, I retrieve the data from the ring buffer:
size_t item_size;
size_t item_max_size = hex_block_size;

char *item = (char *)xRingbufferReceiveUpTo(data_in_rbuf_handle, &item_size,
                                      pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000), item_max_size);
//
// Check received data
if (item != NULL) {
  //  Print item
  ESP_LOGW(TAG,
           "***DEBUGGING*** Ring Buffer -> maximum amount of bytes to "
           "retrieve: <%zu> ",
           item_max_size);
  ESP_LOGW(TAG, "***DEBUGGING*** Ring Buffer -> item: <%s> ", item);
  ESP_LOGW(TAG,
           "***DEBUGGING*** Ring Buffer -> size of the retrieved item: "
           "<%zu\n> ",
           item_size);
  // Return item
  vRingbufferReturnItem(data_in_rbuf_handle, (void *)item);
} else {
  // Failed to receive item
  ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to receive item\n");
}

Just an example, hex_block_size is 230.
The ring buffer sould have all this data:
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
And I only want to retrieve hex_block_size bytes (230) at a time, so in the variable item I expect to have: 80011AD87641F29CD1529B3F3409EF544B01324C6D59115BFEBC193F82342ED8336D48BEC7ED987D5046114F192251186AE32E756845DA74C06CB7B4D203117D5DB681195F88943411EF7EEA9149355955868643D22FBB2151D73B37F6B9D21C9C0427365A467F3D967330812D80D9D789EC9B
But instead of that, item has the whole content of the ring buffer.
So I'm missing something out here. The create, send and receive functions are all extracted from the documentation.

You seem to be mixing up raw data and strings. Which format are you dealing with? char is for strings and strings need to be null terminated in that case. For raw data use uint8_t.

Why not show us the copy/paste of the report that is being logged: "***DEBUGGING*** Ring Buffer -> size of the retrieved item: "? Does that report 230 and are you just getting confused because item is pointing to ALL of the data in the ring buffer? You're meant to do something with the bytes you've "fetched" before calling vRingbufferReturnItem(), letting the RB functions know you're done with that bit. (That last function call is a bit like "free these (230?) bytes back into the free space of the RB because I don't need them anymore, but hang onto whatever follows these bytes.")

char *DataLength; simply doesn't look right. And, strlen(Lora_data.Data) seems a bit off, too...

The documentation is not explicit, but the interface suggests that xRingbufferReceiveUpTo() uses zero-copy semantics.  Meaning that the returned pointer is a pointer to a location within the ring buffer, not a copy of such data.
The receive function will modify the state of the ring buffer such that subsequent retrievals will move the returned pointer to the next block.
In any event, if you observe the memory at the returned pointer, you will see other data in the ring buffer that is not part of the currently retrieved data (it remains in the buffer for later retrieval).
The only valid data you should process following the call is from item[0] to item[item_size-1].  Often you might want to memcpy() that data to a buffer so that you can release the buffer block (vRingbufferReturnItem) at the earliest opportunity.
All that said, if your message blocks are always the same fixed size, a message queue rather than a byte buffer might be more appropriate.  That way you will not need the separate task-signalling.  You simply wait in a complete 230 byte message to be posted.  A message queue has FIFO semantics like a ring buffer, but for fixed length messages as you appear to be using.  Moreover a message queue has built-in task synchronisation and is safe from overrun of data yet to be read.  On the other hand it is not zero-copy, so less resource and CPU efficient in some cases.

I'm pretty sure it's vRingbufferReturnItem() that releases sections back to be re-used (in ring buffer fashion). There should be no "overwrite". The attempt xRingbufferSend() should fail if there's insufficient space available. Worth noting that reading is like reading from a file. When wrapping request would require "wrapping around to top of buffer", the "read back" pointer obviously does NOT "wrap". Instead, one only gets as much as is available to the bottom of the block. Caller must splice two bits together, if necessary.

I thought that too, take the data from item[0] to item[item_size-1]. The message queue you talk about is the message buffer feature from RTOS???

@AndyDuarte https://www.freertos.org/a00018.html

@Fe2O3  - that is what comes from trying to read the documentation on my phone!   I was thinking of a generic ring buffer without RTOS locks. It is a weird name as it is not really returning the item, but returning the memory for reuse.   Nonetheless I still assume it is zero-copy and that this answer applies.   Will clean it up lest it distract from the main point.

@AndyDuarte "I thought that too, take the data from item[0] to item[item_size-1]." : Yes, that is what item_size is for.  It is not clear in your question what your observation is but item_size will never be greater than item_max_size and anything beyond item[item_size-1] is not part of the retrieved "item", and should not be accessed.

"such that subsequent retrievals will move" I had a working ESP32 program (a few years ago) using these RTOS functions. Always used "get, release, get, release, ..." to advance through the buffer (playback with one 'cursor'). I never tried (never considered) "get, get, release, release" (playback with 'n' cursors). I'd be sceptical about that working. If the 2nd get is allowed, I'd expect pointer to be same as 1st get. Too much temptation to try using RB as "malloc/free" of object pool blocks. Shouldn't encourage OP until OP fixes-up Q to be something useful. It's a mess, now.
